# Can Q-table learned by specific stock be applied to only that stock?

Tags: machine-learning

Let say I develop [Q-learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-learning) strategy to predict IBM's stock price.

So, it means that Q-table is created based on past IBM stock price data.

In this case, this Q-table could be applied only to `IBM` future price prediction?

What about applying it to `APPLE`? Would it be possible?

Comment: what is Q-learning? Can you explain this and how it works?

Comment: AFAIK both approaches have been tried. If you use IBM trained prediction on AAPL you might have to pre-condition the data to make it comparable...